# The server list from source engine games only show very few servers

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2, garrys-mod

Both Gmod and TF2 only show me like 10 servers, yet games like tabletop simulator shows all server available, so i know there is a problem with source games.

I tried lowering max ping and clear download cache, but nothing happens.

Comment: Did you try one of these (or all of them)? -> check/disable anti virus (especially Norton is a pain), check your proxy settings (try it without proxy), add port forwarding rules for common [Steam ports](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8571-GLVN-8711) in your firewall/router.

Comment: How long have you waited? It may take some time for Gmod to find all available servers.

Comment: Also there is an option on Steam to limit server discovery rate. In this case it will take some time to list all available servers. I highly doubt you activated it without knowing, cause many never ever discover it even when searching.

Answer (score 2):

All source games use the same algorythm of discovering servers:

- the game asks valve's masterserver for a server list, receiving a list of IP addresses
- the game now sends an [A2S_INFO](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries#A2S_INFO) UDP packet to *each* server in a list, at a maximum rate of 250-5000 pings per minute.
- every servers responds with an UDP response packet containing some useful information

#### Why this happens

Most likely, your internet connection have issues with UDP packets: packet loss, extreme delaying, restrictive filter, etc etc. - packets between you and internet servers lost.. somehow.

### What you can do

#### 1. Decrease server query rate

Rate is guessed by steam client, but it's also configurable in

```
Settings -> In-game -> In-Game Server browser: Max pings / minute
```

[image: Settings -> In-game -> In-Game Server browser: Max pings / minute]

#### 2. Hit refresh servers button again

With my 3G connection it takes multiple clicks, and from 5 to 30 seconds before servers in TF2 client start to appear.

#### 3. Troubleshoot network issues

Anti-virus, firewall or other software may interfere, try disabling it.

Bad hardware (notably your router) can interfere - try connecting to internet directly (if your pc connected  to isp through router)

If none helps, you can call your ISP's customer support.